# Launching a 64-bit command prompt from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, external-tools

Is there a way by which a 64 bit command prompt can be launched from Visual Studio 2010 Express? I understand I can create a custom tool to do this, but VS being a 32-bit application by itself, it only launches a 32-bit command prompt. Any ideas?

Edit:
Sorry for not being clearer. I am using the web developer express edition for developing a non-.NET mobile application and need to use a 64-bit command prompt to package the mobile application.

Comment: Create a small console application, compile it in 64bit - all this needs to do is start a 64bit command prompt...

Comment: I went with your suggestion moontear and passed through all input arguments to a command prompt and it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing the 64-bit command prompt does is set the paths so the 64-bit C/C++ compiler, linker and libraries are getting used instead of the 32-bit versions.  Pretty sure you don't have any since you got an Express edition.  Check for the presence of the vc\bin\amd64 and vc\bin\x86_amd64 directories in the install directory.  The 64-bit setup is selected by passing "x64" to vcvarsall.bat instead of "x86".

This is all assuming you got the C++ Express edition, not clear from the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for not mentioning that I am using VWD Express for a reason, it was not meant to be. :) moontear's approach helped me wriggle out.

Answer (score 1):

64-bit tools aren't included in the Express editions.

You can install the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924), which includes a command prompt (and of course all the 64-bit tools and compilers you'll need).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for not mentioning that I am using VWD Express for a reason, it was not meant to be. :) moontear's approach helped me wriggle out.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1?

Open your ordinary Visual Studio Command Prompt and type:

```
setenv /x64
```

If your 64bit compilers are missing, you might need to read [KB2519277](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277).