# Installing packages when running multiple versions of Python on Windows

Tags: python, installation, package

I am running `Python 2.7` and `Python 3.4` on Windows and am trying to install packages to `Python 3.4`, while `Python 2.7` is my default. I'm using the same idea as in the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251314/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), as I got the same Windows VCVARSALL  error described in the post.

For example I am currently trying to install `numpy-1.9.2+unoptimized-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl` as my Computer is a Windows 8.1, 64 bit machine. However, I get the error `numpy-1.9.2+unoptimized-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform` and don't know why.

Comment: Are you using `pip` or `pip3`?

Comment: Then try `pip3`, or use the `cp27` wheel - you can't install that version of `numpy` to Python 2.7.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I might be confused. I want to install that version of `numpy` to Python 3.4

Comment: Yes, but **that's not what you're doing**. `pip` will be trying to install things to Python 2.7, `pip3` to 3.4.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank You. However, when I replace `pip` with `pip3` in my Command Prompt, I get the Error `pip3 is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Could you suggest how I proceed from here?

Comment: Try making the working directory `C:\Python34\Lib` and running `pip` there. Otherwise, I suggest you spend some time researching how to get Windows set up for Python dev - there are lots of resources on that already. You may find it easier with a `virtualenv`, so you can specify the interpreter once then be sure you're using the same one.