# ImportError for NumPy/SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, import, scipy

I am trying to run some code that requires importing NumPy and SciPy (I'm using Python 3.4), but I keep getting the following message (my OS is Windows):

```
import numpy as np # used for linear algebra

ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have already downloaded NumPy but I don't know how to set it up correctly. Is there any way to fix this? I've been having this error for a while already.

Update: I found the solution. Apparently I had already downloaded both Anaconda (a distribution of Python) and Python, so I deleted both of them and installed back Anaconda, rebooted the computer and now everything works perfectly (can use NumPy and SciPy).

Comment: after downloading did you run python setup.py install on those files

Comment: I already did for those files.

Comment: What source did you download and what command did you use to install?

Comment: What do you mean with the source? And I did not use any command (I just executed setup.py). How can I go around this? I'm very new to Python.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010 installed as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251314/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)? To install numpy you have several installation options. After Visual C++ 2010 is installed, you can use pip or install numpy using [source files or precompiled installers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/).

Comment: I don't see Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010 listed. Which installation should I choose? Is the Visual Studio Community 2013 enough for this purpose?

Comment: How did you install them?