# Cannot install Scrapy in virtual environment

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a virtual environment in windows to run Python 3.4.3. I tried installing Scrapy package using two ways:

1. Using pip command (with latest pip 9.0) by entering in command line as follows:

   pip install scrapy
2. By downloading zipped setup file from scrapy website and then installing it by entering in command line as follows:

   python setup.py install

With both the ways, I am getting an error displaying Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (vcvarsall.bat). I tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 but during installation it displayed that I already had Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed and it could not continue the installation of version 10.0 without uninstalling 14.0 first. Unfortunately, my other programs depends on ver 14.0 and I cannot uninstall it. I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

[image: Error]

How can I resolve this error?

Update: I have successfully re-installed Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 x64 redistributable package but unfortunately I am not able to locate the its folder in Program files or Program files (x86) [obviously not here!] to set the environment variables as suggested in other in similar posts in Stackover flow.

Comment: I have installed scrapy in Python 3.6 and it seems to be working fine as it required Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 which is available in my system. But the above problem still remains a mystery. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Maybe this blog post will help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/ It recommends to download Visual Studio 2010 or Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET 4.0. Alternatively, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31184395/3004221 suggests using Visual Studio 2010 Express. (Of course you might need another SDK, but .NET 4.0 might be an option you are missing.)

Comment: Naseef, please provide your solution as a response instead of an update to your question.