# Unable to install Pandas in Python 3.4

Tags: pandas, python-3.4

I am trying to install Pandas module in Python version 3.4 (for Windows XP support). However, I am getting following error:

```
    UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.4\pandas/_version.py
    set build\lib.win32-3.4\pandas/_version.py to '0.22.0'
    running build_ext
    building 'pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

    ----------------------------------------

Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\users\\cardio\\Temp\\pip-build-5xhz4ymf\\pandas\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close(); exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record C:\users\cardio\Temp\pip-prngb6r2-record\install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in C:\users\cardio\Temp\pip-build-5xhz4ymf\pandas\
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: It looks like it wants you to update some other software first?

Comment: Hmm, it seems need install `Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0` from [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: What command should I give to upgrade all packages (in Windows)?

Comment: It is not working even after installing from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555 . Same error message: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).` Do I need to restart my computer?

Comment: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/fix-pip-install-unable-find-vcvarsallbat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161635/microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251314/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat No offense intended if you have looked at those already and they didn't help.

Comment: Yes, I have seen these and I realize it is a complex problem.