# Can't Install Python Libraries with C Dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++, pymssql

I'm currently running Python 3.4 on Windows 8.1 using PyCharm Community 5.0.3 and I've been running into the following error when I try to install libraries with C dependencies (ie pymssql):

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)
```

I've gone through various Stack Overflow responses to similar situations but haven't been able to find a viable answer as most of the questions are for Python 2.7. The main response I have found is to re-download Visual Studio 10, which I haven't been able to find at all on the web.

Any insight into this matter would be great.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2817869/284795

Comment: @ColonelPanic I tried doing what was recommended in that post but it still resulted in an error.

Comment: here's the same situation solved, maybe it would help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251314/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: @noise It doesn't look like there's a prebuilt distribution of pymssql available. I did try installing a .whl version of the library but it failed to install.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can Download  Microsoft Visual 2013 Redistributable Packages from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

You can also use Mingw as a **compiler** for python 2.x and also for 3.x

check this documentation : https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/#gnu-c-cygwin-mingw

This allows you to have  compiler to build your extensions for your python,to use mingw as a compiler for python you have to :

1-install mingw32 to **C:\programs\mingw**

2-Add mingw32's bin directory to your environment variable: append **c:\programs\MinGW\bin;** to the **PATH**

3-Edit (*create if not existing*) **distutils.cfg** file located at C:**\Python2\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg** to be:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

Now run easy_install.exe to install any module using c or c++ extensions :)