# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). while installing Scrapy on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: python, c++, windows, python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to install Scrapy.

I am getting this error. I know there are many questions exists on SO but none of a solution has worked for me.

```
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Mani\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-eav78sdn\\Twisted\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Mani\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-19_gmj4b-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Mani\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-eav78sdn\Twisted\
```

I have these things installed in my computer

[image]

I have System Variable name:value is `VS100COMNTOOLS:VS140COMNTOOLS`

I also have OpenSSL installed in `OpenSSL-Win64` and added to Windows `PATH`

I also have `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7` installed.

What should I do? I have tried all solutions provided on SO but none worked.

Comment: _"I have tried all solutions provided on SO but none worked."_ Some links to prove that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ http://stackoverflow.com/a/32006750/4094231 this one

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ http://stackoverflow.com/a/27672491/4094231 this one too

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Someone on SO commented about upgrading PIP ... I did that too

Comment: You're using 3.4, so you need Visual Studio 2010 -- not Visual Studio 2013 and not VC++ for Python 2.7. If you can't obtain VS 2010, then update to use Python 3.5 with the latest Visual Studio 2015, community edition.

Comment: @eryksun what if I install Visual Studio 2010 Test Professional 

will that work?

Comment: If you really have to use 3.4, you could try building the extension using MinGW instead of Visual Studio. While you can't build Python itself with MinGW, it does allow building most extension modules. However, you may need to get a lot of help on forums to build everything you need.

Comment: Twisted is not yet supported on Windows with Python 3. Twisted is a requirement for Scrapy. [Twisted seems to be on its way to support Python 3 on Windows](http://labs.twistedmatrix.com/2016/08/twisted-1640-released.html) soon though: _"35+ more modules ported to Python 3, and many many cleanups on the way to Python 3 on Windows support."_

Answer (score 1):

I got this working.

Usually these require very particular versions of the Visual studios C++ compiler. In this case, following the steps listed on [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_10.0_standalone:_Windows_SDK_7.1_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ia64.29) for the *"Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 standalone: Windows SDK 7.1"* worked for getting twisted running (which is the package that's screwing up in this case)

If that doesn't work, you can find unofficial wheels [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (learn more on wheels in general [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/))

Download the correct wheel (in this case, twisted) and [follow these instructions to install it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation)

Hope this helps.