# Failed building wheel for Twisted Command

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++, spyder

I'm working on a crypto trading bot to interface with the Binance API. There has been a toolkit somebody has developed to interface with Binance easier (I haven't spent the time to learn Python HTTP Requests for REST APIs yet) and I am attempting to install this toolkit, which is where I am running into trouble.

The module wiki can be found here: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The error occurs while using `!pip install python-binance` in Spyder. I keep getting an error and have spent hours repairing my Visual C++ 2015, 2017, etc. and trying to find them to add to my python path in case that was the issue.

Omitting all of the installation steps it spits out in my python console, it errors once it reaches this point every time. Unfortunately that landing hub link page isn't found. I've gone to Microsoft and updated to the latest versions as well. I'm guessing this has somethign to do with my paths in spyder, but I can't even find the Visual files in my computer beyond Visual Studio 8.

> building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for Twisted Command "c:\users\g\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import
> ```
>
> setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eyvyab9r\Twisted\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vdboumt8\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eyvyab9r\Twisted\"

Comment: Please provide an introductory paragraph or two to explain what it is that you are wanting to accomplish with this install. Some context for the actual issue you are running into, why you are doing this and what you expect to accomplish, would be helpful. Some idea as to why you would get the error message referencing "landinghub.visualstudio.com" would be helpful. It appears that it was a repository in visualstudio.com that contained source code or tools of some kind. Does the owner's website https://www.hubspot.com/ have any of those?

Comment: Also see this forum posting https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2079 as well as https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2441 as well as https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/

Comment: Thanks Richard, updated with a little introduction.

Comment: Take a look at what seem to be similar questions in stackoverflow to see if they help you and let us know.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949519/error-while-installing-lxml-through-pip-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537303/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-whi

Comment: There is this page in the python wiki describing the various compiler options https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers with a link to this page about Python Wheel http://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.