# "vcvarsall.bat" issue while building SWIG on Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, swig, quantlib-swig

Following instructions from: [Build QuantLib for Python(SWIG)](http://www.smileofthales.com/build-quantlib-for-python/)

```
python setup.py build --compiler=msvc
```

I wonder why `vcvarsall.bat` cannot be found. Actually, this `batch` file is found at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC
```

Furthermore, I've copied it to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools
```

and have finally added the latter path to the `System variables -> PATH`, without any improvement.

***Ps:*** A similar topic has been raised on [error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat(DUPLICATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251314/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), but none of the solutions advocated have so far helped me in overcoming this matter.

Any relevant feedback would therefore be appreciated.

**OS:** Windows 10

**Studio:** Express 2013 for Windows Desktop

**Boost:** v.1_58_0

**SWIG:** v.1_6

**QuantLib:** v.1_6

**IDE:** PTVS v.2.2.2

Thanks in advance

**1 - EDIT:** See below the screenshot (incl. error)

[image]

**Alternatively:**

```
=======================================================================
C:\local\QuantLib_SWIG_1_6\Python>python setup.py build --compiler=msvc
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'QuantLib._QuantLib' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
========================================================================
```

**2 - EDIT:**

I've even gone further by updating the `get_build_version()` method from the module: `msvc9compiler.py` held in

`C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\Lib\distutils` To:

```
#if majorVersion >= 13: updated
if majorVersion > 13:
    # v13 was skipped and should be v14
    majorVersion += 1
elif majorVersion == 13: #v13 no more skipped, UPDATED  on 11/13/2016   
      majorVersion -= 1 # pointing specifically to v.12
```

since my `Python 3.5.2` was compiled under `MSC 1900 <=> VS 2015`. However it's look like the compiler cannot be found as console (`cmd`) still returns

```
error:Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

*Ps*: Totally amazed with this installation. Solution of last resort: Install `VS2015 Community` that I was postponing

**3 - EDIT:**

```
set MSSdk=1
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
python setup.py build

Error:
The program can't start because mspdb120.dll is missing from your computer. 
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem  
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  
12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe Failed with exit status - 10737441515
```

*Solution:*

Copy `mspdb120.dll` To `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64`

```
python setup.py build
quantlib_wrap.cpp
QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp: fatal error C1902: Program database manager  
mismatch; please check your installation 
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio   
12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe Failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: If you know whether you are using a 32 or 64 bit platform, look for vcvars32.bat or arm/vcvars64.bat in the VC/bin directory.  vcvarsall.bat is just a front end for calling one of them.  vcvarsall probably only exists in the full blown version so you're looking at something like vs2013/2015 community edition.

Comment: I am using a `64-bit` windows. thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look.

Comment: Alternatively, run it from the cmd prompt  provided by Visual Studio.  That will set up all the paths for your environment.

Comment: @cup: same outcome, fyi.

Comment: The error message `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` is definitely not output by Windows command interpreter. This error message is output by the used Python script. So we need to know how `setup.py` searches for this batch file, i.e. need the block in `setup.py` around `vcvarsall.bat`.

Comment: I agree. Interestingly, `setup.py` does not explicitly call somehow `vcvarsall.bat`. If you'd like I can only disclose the `block` around the `msvc` compiler so you'll see that none of the `class members` have been omitted there from the previous `cmd`

Comment: @Mofi: [SWIG-1.6.zip ---> Python\setup.py](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/1.6/other%20languages/)

Comment: I could see the same by looking on [setup.py](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/master/Python/setup.py) on GitHub. I'm not familiar with Python, but it looks like we need to investigate the __distutils__ package. There is only Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 mentioned on [Build QuantLib for Python(SWIG)](http://www.smileofthales.com/build-quantlib-for-python/) Most likely this package is not prepared for Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 at all.

Comment: @Mofi: Might be... Unfortunately I have not got a confirmation so far based on my searches. Reason why i was keep on installing it using `Express 2013` by acknowledging that the `vcvarsall.bat` error sounds a bit `irrational` (to me), since the `batch` is clearly found and included in `PATH`

Comment: @dark.vador I downloaded [SWIG-1.6.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/1.6/other%20languages/) and ran multiple searches on all files for `vcvarsall`, `vars`, `vc`, `bat`, `.bat` but could not find any relevant. As my Python knowledge is very poor, I can't help further on your problem. My last advice is using free Sysinternals [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) with an __include__ filter for __Path contains vcvarsall__ and look on the file system log after running Python command line.

Comment: @Mofi: Only "potential" _counter-argument_ is the installation made by the following author [nstalling QuantLib and QuantLib-Python in Windows using VS Expess 2013](https://vineetv.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/installing-quantlib-python-windows/)...I will consequently work on it since it's a slightly different `cmd` approach but apparently they've managed to install it via `VS 2013`.

Comment: @Mofi: No worries... Please, note that I am grateful to your `free` time devoted to this post as well as the previous details provided. Best

Answer (score 0):

`vcvarsall.bat` is needed only when running Visual C/C++ compiler from outside Visual Studio. It defines all the environment variables needed by Visual C/C++ compiler. This batch file should not be moved to other directories as installed by default as this results in setting up the environment variables wrong.

If this batch file needs to be called from another process without using full path, the directory containing `vcvarsall.bat` must be defined either in **user** or **system** `PATH` in Windows advanced environment settings or the directory path is added to **local** `PATH` of the process which calls later this batch file.

Every time a process is started, Windows creates a **copy** of the environment variables table of current process for the new process. This means a modification of environment variable `PATH` within a batch file is only active for the command process executing the batch file and all processes started by this command process after modification of **local** `PATH`. Other processes already running on modifying `PATH` within a command process continue running with their unmodified **local** copy of `PATH`.

So if **user** or **system** `PATH` is modified in advanced system settings of Windows. This modification becomes active for all already running processes only after a complete restart of Windows. The modification of **user** or **system** `PATH` without a restart of Windows becomes only active for processes started from Windows desktop **after** the modification as for those new processes the current environment variables table of Windows desktop is taken as source on creating the copy of the environment variables for the new process.

I suppose you have **appended** to **system** `PATH` the string

```
;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC
```

whereby the semicolon at beginning is needed only if existing `PATH` before modification does not already end with a semicolon.

And after this modification of **system** `PATH` it is best to restart Windows to make it active for all processes.

By the way: I would not append this path to **system** `PATH` as system processes don't need that directory in `PATH`. I would append it to **user** `PATH` or create **user** `PATH` with the directory path if there is currently no `PATH` in user environment table. And most often it is enough to append a specific directory path to **local** `PATH` like here because this directory path is definitely not needed for all processes start as user process.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. Either `user` or `system` **PATH** is used, i end up with the same error (_caeteris paribus_): unable to find `vcvarsall.bat` which is seriously `weird`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the post, by inserting a screenshot (incl. error). Ps: Note that I was using `cmd`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the Python `distutils` package looking for another version of Visual Studio.  As far as I know, Python 2.7 to 3.2 was built with VC++9; versions 3.3 and 3.4 were built with VC++10; and versions of Python from 3.5 onwards are built with VC++14.  When running `distutils`, each of them will look for the corresponding VC++ version unless you specify otherwise. Thus, Python (by the way, which version are you using?) doesn't find your `vcvarsall.bat` from VC++12 because it doesn't look into that path.

According to [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.msvccompiler), the workaround would be to set the environment variables `DISTUTILS_USE_SDK` and `MSSdk` to tell `distutils` that the environment is already set up and that it doesn't need to look for `vsvarsall.bat`. After that, running the script from the command prompt for Visual Studio might work.

This said, it might not be guaranteed that a module compiled with a version of VC++ will work with a Python compiled with a different one, so you might want to install and use the one corresponding to your Python installation.

Comment: Thanks for your conclusion that matches my expectation. Regarding `distutils`, it's worth pointing that by default `msvc9compiler.py` was skipping `VC++12`, reason why I've amended it (i.e EDIT) hoping that while running the script from the command prompt `vcvarsall.bat  = os.path.join(productdir, "vcvarsall.bat")` held in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools` would be found. I would consequently have a look at the advocated `DISTUTILS_USE_SDK` , and as a solution of last resort I would have to install `VS2015 Community`. Best

Comment: Your suggested workaround with `DISTUTILS_USE_SDK` and `MSSdk` is fine, however it triggers another set of `errors` on which I am working (i.e 3-EDIT). Any sharing of what's going on with `quantLib_wrapp.cpp` would thus be appreciated. Best

Comment: Sorry, no idea what's going on with `quantlib_wrap.cpp`. The acronym suggests that the error about a Program DataBase mismatch is related to the msPDB dll you copied, though. The compiler might be taking a harder look and deciding it's not the one it was expecting.

Comment: No worries, Luigi. Best,