# Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7

When I want to install packages, including Jupyter, I get the error that Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. I get the same error with Pip and pre-compiled binaries on UC website.

I have Visual Studio 17 express installed and I have manually added the path of `vcvarsall` to my environment.

I also saw solution to update the `VS###COMMONTOOLS`, however `VS###COMMONTOOLS` variable doesn't exist.

I am using Windows Server 2012.

How can I proceed?

Comment: If this is a duplicate, why *shouldn't* it be marked as such? Duplicate of what - could you provide links? What do you mean *"doesn't exist"* (and what's with the extra characters)?

Comment: here is a couple link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210299/error-microsoft-visual-c-9-0-is-required
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251314/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

none of those really have a solution, they have suggestions and those suggestions are not working.

Comment: Then [edit] the question to say that - what have you tried, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Answer (score 43):

Download the archived version of Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from the following link:

[web.archive.org mirror: Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://web.archive.org/web/20190720195601/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266)

Answer (score 19):

Download and install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from the following link:
[Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://web.archive.org/web/20210106040224/https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi)

Comment: Nice, but i must be missing the runtime, i now get `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory`

Answer (score -2):

Leaving this here for the next time I run into this problem. For me, builds were failing via CI (Jenkins), but working for my user. Eventually I figured out that VCPython doesn't install system wide. I had to use runas to open a command prompt as the Local System user and then run the installer from that command prompt. Hopefully this helps someone else!