# ERROR : Microsoft visual C++ 9.0 is required

Tags: python

I am trying to install PyRQA with pip but i keep got the error:

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required.Can someone please explain to me exactly what i have to do to fix this error( simple and detailed explanation)? I am using python 2.7.16 (I know this has been answered before but i did not understand it).I am working on windows 8.

Comment: Well, the error message will not get more clear on what is missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645519/microsoft-visual-c-9-0-is-required)

Comment: Is there something you don't understand about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Download Microsoft C++ compiler for python..

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: Yes.I downloaded it...But still got another error:
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo B490\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Mi
crosoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status2