# Problems with installing netCDF4==1.4.2

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pip, netcdf4

I am trying to install netCDF4==1.4.2 using "pip install netCDF4==1.4.2" to use in jupyter notebook.

I am running

```
Windows 10 enterprise 64 bit.
python                        3.10.9
anaconda-client               1.11.2
anaconda-navigator            2.4.0
anaconda-project              0.11.1
conda                         23.3.1
conda-build                   3.24.0
conda-content-trust           0.1.3
conda-pack                    0.6.0
conda-package-handling        2.0.2
conda_package_streaming       0.7.0
conda-repo-cli                1.0.41
conda-token                   0.4.0
conda-verify                  3.4.2
ipykernel                     6.19.2
ipython                       8.10.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipywidgets                    7.6.5
jupyter                       1.0.0
jupyter_client                7.3.4
jupyter-console               6.6.2
jupyter_core                  5.2.0
jupyter-server                1.23.4
jupyterlab                    3.5.3
jupyterlab-pygments           0.1.2
jupyterlab_server             2.19.0
jupyterlab-widgets            1.0.0
pip                           23.2
```

But, I am getting this error when using the Anaconda Prompt.

```
(base) C:\\Users\\79\>pip install netCDF4==1.4.2

Collecting netCDF4==1.4.2
Using cached netCDF4-1.4.2.tar.gz (769 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[19 lines of output\]
C:\\Users\\79\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2bd1mj_1\\netcdf4_e3f1e4ce8f52415499486dd692dea5ae\\setup.py:170: DeprecationWarning: The SafeConfigParser class has been renamed to ConfigParser in Python 3.2. This alias will be removed in Python 3.12. Use ConfigParser directly instead.
config = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<string\>", line 2, in \<module\>
File "\<pip-setuptools-caller\>", line 34, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Users\\79\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2bd1mj_1\\netcdf4_e3f1e4ce8f52415499486dd692dea5ae\\setup.py", line 371, in \<module\>
\_populate_hdf5_info(dirstosearch, inc_dirs, libs, lib_dirs)
File "C:\\Users\\79\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2bd1mj_1\\netcdf4_e3f1e4ce8f52415499486dd692dea5ae\\setup.py", line 319, in \_populate_hdf5_info
raise ValueError('did not find HDF5 headers')
ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers
reading from setup.cfg...

          HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
      checking C:\Users\79 ...
      checking /usr/local ...
      checking /sw ...
      checking /opt ...
      checking /opt/local ...
      checking /usr ...
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have tried suggestions in this post [Installing specific package version with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip) to no avail. And https://betterdatascience.com/pip-install-specific-version/. Which was basically updating setuptools, installing ez_isntall, and install unroll (which didn't work).

The same issue occurs if I try to install it through the settings in pycharm. Not too sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netCDF4` 1.4.2 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/1.4.2/#files) for Python 2.7 and 3 up to 3.7. You have Python 3.10 so `pip` is trying to compile `netCDF4` from sources but that requires sources (esp. headers) for HDF5.

Either install HDF5 headers and libraries and compile `netCDF4`. Or downgrade Python to 3.7, then `pip` could use pre-compiled wheel from PyPI. Or use higher version of `netCDF4`; `netCDF4` 1.5.8 and higher [provide wheels](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/1.5.8/#files) for Python 3.10; the [current latest version](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/#history) 1.6.4.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Should I download the latest HDF5? I am using  this link [HDF Group Website](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/). I think I might be confused on what headers and libraries are when it pertains to packages.

Comment: My advice is to use precompiled wheels of `netCDF4`; downgrade Python to 3.7, then `pip` could use pre-compiled wheel from PyPI. Or use higher version of `netCDF4`. Compiling it from sources is hard. See the instructions at https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#developer-install

Comment: So, this is a bit weird. I downgraded to python 2.7 to match the version that the author was using. What I did was installed all of the packages here except netcdf4 and netcdftime as I got errors when installing them still. They are: numpy==1.15.4, pandas==0.24.1, scipy==1.2.0, netcdf4==1.4.2, matplotlib==2.2.3, xarray==0.11.3, statsmodels==0.9.0, cftime==1.0.3.4, netcdftime==1.0.0a2, dask==1.1.1, toolz==0.9.0, AND setuptools==41.2.0. THEN, I was able to install netcdf4==1.4.2. I am now having trouble with netcdftime==1.0.0a2. Python 2.7 had wheel==0.37.1 and pip==20.3.4 preinstalled.

Comment: I still want to go the route you had advised. By using precompiled wheels of netCDF4; downgrade Python to 3.7, then pip could use pre-compiled wheel from PyPI. But, I'm not too sure what "precompiled wheels of netCDF4 means."

Comment: For netcdftime==1.0.0a2. I installed cython==0.28.5 and installed Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645519/microsoft-visual-c-9-0-is-required](Download the archived version of Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from the following link:). Look for the comment that points to the archived link.