# Error during pip install ldavis

Tags: python-3.x, package, pip, lda, installation-package

I have been attempting to install a Python package by the name of 'pyLDAvis' from cmd with no success since over a day now!
I ran the following command from cmd -

```
pip install pyldavis
```

I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.
Further, I have also performed the steps mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513378/3228300 (Installing Win SDK 7.1, change the redistributable pkgs and create a vcvars64.bat file). Sadly, I do not know how to proceed further. I am pasting the ending snippet of code that is thrown back at me when the installation stops below -

```
    c:\users\ABC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\num
py\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disab
le it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /D
LL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\libs" "
/LIBPATH:C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64" /EXPORT:PyInit___sub
sample build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\skbio/stats/__subsample.obj /OUT:build\l
ib.win-amd64-3.4\skbio\stats\__subsample.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Re
lease\skbio/stats\__subsample.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
\skbio/stats\__subsample.pyd.manifest
    __subsample.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit___subsample' specified mul
tiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\skbio/stats\__subsample
.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\skbio/stats\__subsample.exp
    building 'skbio.alignment._ssw_wrapper' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\skbio\alignment
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\skbio\alignment\_lib
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /
nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG "-IC:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\lib\site
-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\include" "-
IC:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\include" /Tcskbio/alignment/_ssw_wrapper.c
/Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\skbio/alignment/_ssw_wrapper.obj -Wno-error=
declaration-after-statement
    cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-error=declara
tion-after-statement'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\B
in\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\python.exe" -c "import setuptools,
 tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ABC1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cp30pok
9\\scikit-bio\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).
read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ABC1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hto4uniu-record\install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ABC1\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-build-cp30pok9\scikit-bio
```

Any suggestions helping me out of this situation are welcome.
P.S. I run Python 3.4 on a Windows 7 desktop (6 GB ram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyldavis does not work for windows machines because sci-kit bio package is not compiled for windows binaries... it seems this will be available mid 2016.

You will need to use Linux or OSX to get pyldavis working.