# Not able to install cryptography package in python

Tags: python, visual-studio, cryptography

I tried to search a lot before asking it here, but unfortunately couldn't find anything helping.

I want to install cryptography package in python3.4.3 64bit version running on (windows 64bit} machine.

I am getting the following error:

{

```
generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-3.4\\Release\\_constant_time.c'

generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-3.4\\Release\\_openssl.c'

building '_openssl' extension

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

}

I do have visual studio 2015 installed and I could find vcvarsall.bat manually,
also my environment variable are pointing to correct folder as suggested in other threads.
`VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools`

These are the sites i already went through looking for help but in vain.

1) Changing the value for VS90COMNTOOLS,

2) I tried with different versions of visual studio greater than 10 i.e 2010,2012,2013.

3) [Python PIP has issues with path for MS Visual Studio 2010 Express for 64-bit install on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473854/python-pip-has-issues-with-path-for-ms-visual-studio-2010-express-for-64-bit-ins)

4) [Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251314/error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

5)https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/

Comment: Could you add in what you have tried from your research that did not work and their outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ship a statically linked wheel for Windows (our [install instructions](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#on-windows) mention this) so all you need to do is be running the latest pip (as of June 2016 this is 8.1.2). To upgrade your pip you can do `python -m pip install -U pip` (`pip install -U pip` will raise an error due to the way Windows does active file locking).

Once that is installed `pip install cryptography` will grab the wheel and not require a compiler at all.